# Constant ramp not behaving as expected in SPICE simulation

Tags: ltspice, simulation, constant-current, linear, ramp-generator

Looking for some advice on creating a constant (linear) ramp which meets a certain specification, I've designed this example which works well in ideal simulation but I cannot get it to work in SPICE. When I simulate in SPICE I find it produces a ramp between 1-3V and a cannot force it negative.

It's part of a simple raster scan board I want to create (this is a Y axis ramp and synced to x axis at 16kHz).

I'm a bit of a hardware noob and this is a project to help me learn so please let me know if there is something obvious I'm missing or some wiki I need to read :)

Spec:
32Hz,
-3V3 to 3V3 linear ramp,
fall time of <30uS

[Ideal sim in Falstad](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l5AWAnC1b0DYQOhgTGBgMxH5gCsAHEnsiOZPfY%20QKYC0YYAUAO4h4A7HhBE8jISKLkRPfpNEzRGSopGRuAJwHCB5LArGMWGONwBKO2YIO6wCBFCcJGYdU5jk%20V8DeWqwPw0AeVFKR3I3bDF6KOMtfzVEhBjXeG4Ac2SY0lUHVXiAFx9pETxaJMZOAWg8UkJBKiRkSkg8JBB2TzwVQKRKPH0EcoRycDgQABNWADMAQwBXABtChJHRUgEKwKxXcXT5bb8FHahuAGMtxyJwq%20j3Ilr0Z9QMDkEoaEEELgxCFLwlCIyEEBVgkB4WXWALu%20Q83GKXBELlcDmwE1cnRwiAoKmIkEoVEJWEekEEbmGwhUiEGjXe40Y03my1Wlk4NCS7HWpScUjK0DGeAFHgFCRiKPAUQlEnE4Pg8vlRG83JUdxujg02m5t3s11ujBU3EmWNUPJySlkADlyOSeNp2AhTUoHXlHbz9hdOm4nSIXZVwPTHkQ4C4bIIkDcIcH1OC5F6OTzOIDKt5zXz0UVROI7gp1lUIFUYKZyOQkGASBQUhCbQyprNFisEVmZddVXmvSBKNAfoIyc1pBhGqNVF1cJAS2WK%20QqxQPmAJkyG6t5LpxKoTkFU22CYlThp%20EY1dnBrtlauXD4T2cV2V9M29KeD6rD7kknHXy%202xeNHMBJRVJEUi3IBIAdBQXpjPOCqfN8XDTnUgQ-GArQal8SF-BgAJAiCAQKsq-70McBEyAUyoVOqf6mvq%20FUY4gJ5Egj7gGiPxYLq2BuvuzGOHCfpwiE3EcQELGtOAZxski9BopwUSlu4jAXkmHifF4WScGiFHqTxGJnMCIAAF6sAAdqwmjsF27hgF89ilJQYA0HZ8B4PSEidrUZz6V6UqMV5yJuiIhkmWZFkJDJQGOGFQlOFBXFaWEEWSRRsWSbxbr8Z6nB%20LxpzThqAbsB8XYYCgcm9ggghELauyxt4mVYLlvlSRqtWnNlUqcamwF%20BRIEaMakXIFgkUNSIi4sp1EREQBm4APZMO4KT4CAGC4AMlCmJAGHkoCMbwAW4DcHN4F5S4SAfGMMBtJBAjgGMSpAA)

Comment: You're asking about something that doesn't work (in SPICE) yet you show only the working Falstad version. Also include the non-working version. If you made the exact same thing it should work in the same way also in (LT)Spice.

Comment: Yeah, which spice software can't you get this to work in? In LTspice you can use a pulse voltage source with the parameters (-3.3 3.3 0 0.3125 30u 1p 0.03125) and get the desired waveform. Unless you are trying to make a circuit discretely.

Comment: I simulated the circuit in the Falstad link in LTspice and it works as it should. Show us your simulation circuit (schematic and salient waveform plots). Failure (as long as nobody gets hurt) is a good way to learn, so don't be embarrassed to post your implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Research the [LTSpice PWL](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-piecewise-linear-functions-for-voltage-current-sources.html) (piece-wise linear) volage/current source.

In that source, you define a series of data points [time,voltage]. Interpolation between points is linear, so you'd need one point at time 0 (-3.3v), another at 1/32Hz (+3.3v), another at 1/32Hz + 20us (-3.3V), etc.

Comment: Ill do some reading, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple voltage source and set it to PULSE-Mode. There you can specify rise and fall time. In order to make it a ramp the **Ton[s]** and **Tperiod[s]** must be 0. If you add some parameters it looks like this:

[image: linear ramp]

Just copy and paste:

- voltage source: `PULSE({Vmin} {Vmax} 0 {1/f-tfall} {tfall} 0 0 0)`
- parameters: `.param f=32 tfall=30u Vmin=-3.3 Vmax=3.3`

If you want to add a delay the first 0 has to be changed. If you only want a certain amount of pulses the last 0 sets the number (0 means infinite).